# OpenGapps problem in Redmi 4X with LineageOS

Tags: lineageos, 9.0-pie, redmi, gapps

I am running [LineageOS 16](https://download.lineageos.org/santoni) on a Redmi 4X device.

I tried installing the relevant [opengapps pico version](https://opengapps.org/) selecting ARM64 and Android 9.

I booted to TWRP, selected install and clicked on the opengapps zip file. It installed successfully with absolutely NO error code whatsoever. I then cleared Dalvik/cache(TWRP menu after installing opengapps) and rebooted to system.

I ran through setup and it all finished smoothly. I can install apps from the play store and all services too are working.

[image: However this keeps happening and android says that setup keeps crashing.]

However this keeps happening and android says that setup keeps crashing.

I then redownloaded the opengapps zip again,rebooted to TWRP and installed it again. There was no error message. This time I booted to system without clearing Dalvik/Cache.

I ran through setup again. Everything happened properly, all my google stuff is working but again this setup screen keeps reappearing and Android keeps saying that setup keeps crashing.

[image: crashes right after this screen when i click not now]
It crashes right after this screen when I click not now.

[image]

Even now this notification is always present in the notification bar.
[image: All my google apps are working but this is still in the notification bar!!]

Surprisingly all my google apps are still working perfectly including play store,gmail,classroom. I can also call, get messages and do everything else a phone is supposed to do.

[This thread](https://amp.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/dh8co0/lineageos_16_for_redmi_4x_santoni_got_rescueparty/) talks about bootloop which is definitely NOT my issue. I didn't find any other thread related to santoni+lineageos16.

[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/234157/342189) is how I went about rooting my device.

I don't know how to obtain android system logs/logs relevant to opengapps so I am unable to post any of them. I will really appreciate any help I get since this is becoming quite annoying.

Comment: in addition to Morpheus you could also try older [open_gapps](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opengapps/files/arm64/20200705/open_gapps-arm64-9.0-pico-20200705.zip/download) releases. make sure to format system + data + cache before flashing lineageos + gapps + addonsu

Comment: refer to 4. + 5. on LineageOS [Installation instructions](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/santoni/install#installing-lineageos-from-recovery)

Answer (score 1):

- make sure you flashed right version
- try flashing another package but same version
- Possible bug on Rom try Contact on XDA Devlopers

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have solved my own question(again)!!

Turns out Redmi Phones have some problems with encryption which I figured out after reading [this section](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/santoni/install#installing-lineageos-from-recovery).

When I had initially installed my system, I didn't Format the storage, I only wiped the data on it. I feel this was the cause of the problem.

What I have done since is, booted into TWRP, formatted storage after wiping data then I tried installing LineageOS.

Unfortunately that didn't work because LineageOS needs Magisk binaries to function(I expect because of their inbuilt control superuser access feature).

So I wiped all data again,installed Magisk, then I installed the exact same pico opengapps version and this time it worked flawlessly.

When I had installed ArrowOS on my Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus, I hadn't formatted it either and I had installed ArrowOS before Magisk. However it worked because that phone didn't have any funky encryption going on and ArrowOS doesn't have any built-in "superuser access control".

Hence for anyone new to rooting I would advise to format the storage first to avoid any problems down the road.